# When echo text in .tcsh file the less command is not working properly

Tags: linux, echo, tcsh

I have a strange problem that I didn't able to find solution for it:
When I login to my environment it configured to work with tcsh (I want to keep it like that), but when I edit the file ".tcshrc" and put the below code (Only these 2 lines), the text is printed correctly in RED, but after that the "less" command is not working anymore.
When I remove this line, less command works properly.

```
#!/bin/tcsh
echo "THIS LINE IS OK"
```

Does someone knows what could be the reason? I'm using less version: (less 436)

I create a text file: "dummy.txt" and write the following text inside: "THIS IS A DUMMY FILE"

CMD: cat dummy.txt

```
OUTPUT:
```

> THIS IS A DUMMY FILE

CMD: less dummy.txt

```
OUTPUT:
```

> THIS LINE IS OK
>   dummy.txt (END)

Only less command is not working, other commands: cat, more, vi are working properly.

Thanks in advance to the once who try to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the issue, it is well explained in the following link:
http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/faq.html#profileout

I have moved my code to ".login" instead.